# Where are Kofax rejection note messages stored?

Tags: kofax

The Error Text shown in Batch Manager can be found in the Kofax database but where are the rejection note messages for each individual documents held? 
We have a large number of batches in Quality Control and I would like to obtain the rejection note/document note messages without opening each batch manually.

Comment: Did you have a look into the XDocs? Just a suspicion but Doc-Related stuff is often to be found rather there.

Comment: Yes, there is an ErrorDescription field in the .xdc files but it is empty for all documents, including those which are rejected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're in the BatchDocument and BatchPage tables, in the Note column.